# $P^2$ blow up nine points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, birational-geometry

I quote the following paragraph form Kollar-Mori on page 22:

Let $X$ be obtained from $P^2$
 by blowing up at the nine
base points of a pencil of cubic curves, all of whose members are
irreducible. Choosing one of the nine points as the zero section,
we get an infinite group of automorphisms of $X$ generated by the
other eight sections. So $X$ has infinitely many (—1)-curves, all of
which span an extremal ray of NE(X). $|-K_X|$ is the elliptic
pencil, thus $-K_X$ is nef, but not ample.

I have following questions in understanding this paragraph:

(1) What does it mean by taking one point as a section? And why from this we can deduce the autommorphism group is infinite and there are infinitely many $-1$ curves.

(2) Why we can deduce that it is nef but not ample?

Comment: Blowing up the base locus of a pencil resolves the rational map $\mathbb P^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb P^1$ to a morphism $X \to \mathbb P^1$. The nine exceptional divisors of the blowup are each isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ via the restriction of this morphism, hence define sections of it. Taking a point as a section simply means labeling one section as $0$ so that the point at which it meets each fiber is chosen as the origin on that elliptic curve.